# http client header authorization when claim based security

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, web-services, http

I am calling a REST api from MVC application where using claims based security.
How would I set the authentication header?
I don't have password so I guess I shouldn't use Basic. If using Bearer how to I get token?

```
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization= new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
    "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
    $"{"username"}:{"password"}")));

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
    "Bearer",token);
```