# How to exchange claims based security with header based according to best-practice in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core, authorization, identityserver4

NB, it's not equivalent to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47023235/http-client-header-authorization-when-claim-based-security) - it's too old and considers other versions/platforms.

We're setting authorization policy like so. It works and I was kind of proud of the solution.

```cs
options.AddPolicy("ClaimPolicy", config =>
{
  config.RequireAssertion(context =>
  {
    ClaimsPrincipal user = context.User;
    Claim awo = user.Claims.Single(a=>a.Type=="awo");
    bool authorized = user.IsInRoleAwo("management");
    return authorized;
  });
});
```

Now, the requirement has changed. The AWO value will still be used but it won't be a part of the access token as a claim in it. Instead, it will be provided to us as the header of the request. Personally, I see it as intuitively suspicious but I couldn't word my reluctance in technical terms, other than it's unconventional and allows the requested to manipulate the security parameter freely. I failed being sufficiently convincing and had to back off. (Undeniably, ones unability to motivate a choice suggests that it wasn't so great one.)

The new version looks like this. The problem is that I can't find any information about hte headers, the request nor HTTP context in there. There are fields for the user and for the resources. That's it.

```cs
options.AddPolicy("HeaderPolicy", config =>
{
  config.RequireAssertion(context =>
  {
    var resource = context.Resource;
    // now what?!
    return true;
  });
});
```

I was hoping that maybe I can obtain the route and pick AWO value from there (as it's a part of the REST path. I've located something in the resource field that could be cast to `(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteEndpoint)context.Resource` and from there, I can obtain `.RoutePattern.RawText` giving me. Regrettably, that produces the actual pattern, i.e. *DemoApi/mixed/{awo}/data* and not the value that's been passed in.

Should I bounce back to **not** reying in headers to pass me the info to be used in `Authorize` picking the policy? Or is there a best-practice approach to getting info on what headers were part of the request (or at least to learn the path **including** the passed parameters)?

I've got a suggestion to create a [custom middleware](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-a-custom-middleware-in-an-asp-net-core-application/) to put in between `AddAuthentication()` and `Add Authorization` and possibly a [custom authorization handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1#handler-registration-1). I see much higher complexity as a caveat and I can't tell if it's a wise (or even feasible) solution. No blogs discussing it, as far my googling can see. There's an extensive article in that regard on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0#access-mvc-request-context-in-handlers) but it doesn't treat SPA/headers case and, also, seems to me provide the functionality I already have implemented by `RequireAssertion(...)`. There was also a suggestion on applying [API key requirements](https://blog.dangl.me/archive/securing-aspnet-core-controllers-with-a-policy-and-api-keys/) but that seems to me like a lesser security than access tokens obtainable by autorization code flow that we try to achieve.